# Argument data type xml is invalid for argument 1 of len function when comparing two tables through sql diff tool

Tags: sql-server

[image: SQL Diff tool-->Files]
[image: Error Screen shot]

The following error message is being displayed on clicking the compare button in the SQL diff tool

> "Argument data type xml is invalid for argument 1 of len function" when comparing two tables through sql diff tool.

Comment: "SQL Diff tool"?

Comment: Looks more like you have issues in the "SQL diff tool" than with SQL Server. There are a number of data types in SQL Server that does not fare well with the LEN() function and XML is one of them. If you are the author of the diff tool you should probably make use of DATALENGTH() instead.

Comment: yes, SQL Diff Tool.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson for data validation I am using that tool. if the table having a small amount of data working fine, but if a huge amount of data comparing that time it's throwing the error messages. I have attached the screenshot too.

Comment: My searching for ["SQL Diff Tool"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22SQL+Diff+Tool%22&oq=%22SQL+Diff+Tool%22) says there is no such application with that name, @venkatj ...

Comment: @Larnu SQLDBDiff.V5.5.0 also I have attached the screenshot of the tools having the files after extract it. It's a windows based application.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the tool, as @MikaelEriksson says. I suggest raising a support ticket with the provider. [Contacts Page](https://sqldbtools.com/contacts/contacts)

Comment: Thanks, @Larnu for your support. I have raised a support ticket which the link provided by you. Let's see

Comment: Thanks, @MikaelEriksson for your support too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is in regards to a fault with a third party application. This will require attention from the vendor. Volunteers here will be unable to advise on how to fix this as the application is at fault. Only a person who helps develop the application would be able to assist with this, and that support should be provided through the vendor's on support portal.

Comment: If you want to see the code that causes this error you should use SQL Server trace or event session trace for event sqlserver.error_reported or Profiler. This will catch the code sent to server and you'll be able to see what causes the error. But I doubt you can change it within application that it sends